# GitLab 7 CE Omnibus package in centOs7

Tags: package, windows-ce, gitlab, centos7

I have installed a GitLab 7 CE Omnibus package in centOs7. I followed all the installation instructions. Everything worked perfectly until i tried pushing a local repo to the server. When pushing the repo, it asked for my git password. I entered the correct git password but still got this error

```
$ git push -u origin master
git@192.168.1.149's password:
sh: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Most instructions of solving this are for the manually installed GitLab. Has anyone solved the above issue in GitLab 7 CE Omnibus package in centOs7?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use linux "git" user.

You have to create ssh key in your PC.

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$your_email"
Use the code below to show your public key.
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Log in GitLab and paste your public key in your profile.

Please see my question.
[Cannot push into GitLab repository via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623791/cannot-push-into-gitlab-repository-via-ssh)