# cannot push to branch on gitlab with ssh

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I am new to gitlab and this is my first time using ssh. I could generate ssh key and add it into my account settings. I could clone the repo via ssh, I could checkout to my branch, but thing I still cannot do is push my change to the branch. Here is the step by step I generate the ssh key until I try to push it (by following instruction in [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/)):

PS. I am using windows 10.

- on terminal (as admin), type: `ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C
  "myemail@example.com"`.
- Press `Enter` for default path of the ssh key
- Provide password
- Create config file in `~/.ssh/`. Here is what I wrote in the config file:

`Host ahostname
    Hostname myhostname.com
    User mygitlabusername
    Port port
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

- copy the ssh key with this command: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip`
- Placed the ssh key into my account settings
- Then, run `ssh -T git@myhostname.com`, and here is the result:

`The authenticity of host '[myhostname.com]:port ([123.456.789]:port)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[myhostname.com]:port ([ipofmyshost]:port)' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key 'C:~/.ssh/id_rsa':
Welcome to GitLab, <myusername>!`

- Then I try to clone a repo: `git clone ssh://git@myhostname.com/repo.git`
- But, apparently, when cloning, it refer to another IP address. For example, let say `ipofmyhost` on the `ssh -T git@myhostname.com` is `123.456.789`. Then, when I cloning, the IP is changed to `123.456.781` (sorry I am afraid I couldn't mention the real IP). So, here is what I got when try to cloning the repo:

`Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '[123.456.781]:port' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/c/.ssh/id_rsa':`

- But, the clone done, then I checkout to my branch with `git checkout mybranchname`
- Now, I am in my branch. Make little change. Try to `push`, but here is the error I got:

`git@myhostname.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

What I missed here? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623791/cannot-push-into-gitlab-repository-via-ssh) question but sorry I do not understand what the accepted answer suggest me to do to solve this.

**update**

I've try to re-clone again, but before it, I delete all `known_host`. Then, do `git clone` again without testing with `ssh -T git@myhostname.com` to avoid creating new IP address. But, I still got the same error when push my branch even no new ip address added to the `known_host`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again, for testing, with an SSH key created *without* a passphrase.

Or, first, make sure you have added your key to an [ssh-agent with `ssh-add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49488537/6309).
See "[Working with non-default SSH key pair paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths)"

You can "[Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://help.github.com/en/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows)" (GitHub instructions, but valid for GitLab as well)

Comment: I've try with ssh-add but when it executed, the result is "No such file", but I am 100% sure that the file exist. So, I try to create new SSH key without passphrase, AND IT WORKED!!!! Did you know why this happened? I think, by providing password it will be more secure, right?

Comment: @Akza Following https://help.github.com/en/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows, `ssh-add` is used with your private key as parameter: `ssh-add ~/path/to/my_key`. But when you have no passphrase to begin with... this is simpler!

Comment: well, yeah, it much simpler, hahah. But, may I ask one another thing, please? could I use same key for two devices? Let say I generate the first key on windows and now its successfully linked. Now, I want my mac also have access to the repo. Do I have to generate new key on my mac and add it to my profile again? or can I copy the key from my windows to my mac? so I dont have to add new ssh key to my account

Comment: @Akza It is better to generate a new key for the second device, rather than copying the first key. That is because those keys are *private*: as long as they are copied aournd... they are "less private".

Comment: @Akza Plus, you can easily revoke one, without invalidating access for every device.